# How to fetch data in a given interval in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, psql, postgresql-9.1

```
SELECT time,CEIL(AVG(value)) from table 
where col1 = 1 
   and col2='matchThis' 
   and col3>='2022-04-10T18:30:00.00Z' 
   and col3<='2022-04-25T12:58:23.00Z' 
   and mod(to_char(col3, 'MI')::int, 15)=0 
GROUP BY time
```

Semple response of the query to get 15-minute interval data

```
25-04-2022 01:00
25-04-2022 01:15
25-04-2022 01:30
25-04-2022 01:45
```

The above query works fine in 15, 30, and 60 minutes intervals but I have to create a query return interval data as the option shown below.

15 minutes

30 minutes

1 hour

2 hours

6 hours

12 hours

1 day

Comment: You don't seem to have a question.

Comment: The above query not working for 120 minutes(2-hours)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   ceil(avg(column_name)), 
   to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from column_name) / 600 )) *600) 
   AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as interval 
FROM table_name  
   WHERE id=1 
      and column='value' 
      and col >='2022-04-21' 
      and col <= '2022-04-30' 
      GROUP BY interval ORDER BY interval ASC"
```